# Is it possible to set default checked for selected Product Categories?

Tags: magento2.2, magento2.2.6

In magento2 - For some specific requirements, I want to have some of the categories for the products selected by default,

How I can achieve this?

Comment: can you please explain more....

Comment: You means while adding new products categories should be auto selected. Is my understanding correct.

Comment: @HiteshAgrawal - yes you got it absolutely right.